# Drupal's ImageCache module not displaying images

Tags: drupal

i am using drupal 6.x . I used the image cache,gallery formatter modules to display the images.But the image cache contains empty folder.i deleted the .htaccess file in the sies/drfault/file directory.but still the node only displays the image name not images.How to resolve this.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Check the recent log entries (Administer > Reports > Recent log entries) for errors related to Imagecache. That will usually point you to the source of the problem. Also, check out the [Imagecache Troubleshooting documentation](http://drupal.org/node/224913).